# Split html body in two parts

Tags: html, split, height, background-color

Is it possible to split the body tag in my web site into two parts. For example having the first 50% (in height) in the background-color in white and the rest 50% in black?
Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's enough to work with CSS3, then the following do the trick:

```
body {
  background: #000 url(white.png) 0 100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-size: 0 50%;
  -moz-background-size: 0 50%;
  -o-background-size: 0 50%;
  background-size: 0 50%;
}
```

Or you need a (vertically) big enough image, then:

```
body {
  background: #000 url(white.png) 0 50% repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: I see you need it in inverted, then you can change the colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two DIVs for the two colors and place the content in a third div over them.

Answer (score 0):

[Not sure what you mean to 'split' the body but here is how you could do 50% 50% background](http://upwithabang.com/articles/css-split-background-color.html)